# Why is the x axis in this matplotlib plot spaced out?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm quite new to python and I'm just getting into plotting using *matplotlib*.
With the code below, I'm able to make a plot like this:

[image: Plot example]

The numbers present on the x-axis are not meant as numeric values, but rather as sample names. Therefore, they don't have to be spaced out like they are. I thought by making the `"Sample"` variable in the `DataFrame` a `"category"`, I would solve this issue, but this did not work out. I expect that the issue is located at the `"Sample"` argument after `ax.bar`, but I don't (yet) know how to solve this.

```py
# Make Sample a categorial variable instead of numeric
DataFrame['Sample'] = DataFrame['Sample'].astype('category')

#Define Unique samples
samples = DataFrame["Sample"].unique()

#Initiate plot
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

for sample in samples:
    sample_df = DataFrame[DataFrame["Sample"] == sample]
    ax.bar(sample, sample_df["Nucleus_Count"].mean(), yerr = sample_df["Nucleus_Count"].std())
    
ax.set_ylabel("Count")
ax.set_xticks(samples)
plt.show()
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Please create a [minimal *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So include how you import the libraries and generate some example data to reproduce your problem

Comment: Thank you Max, I tried using the reprexpy package with `reprex(venue = 'so')` for this, but I was not entirely sure of the output (it didn't look very nice). I will experiment a bit more with this for my next question in stackoverflow. Luckily @Oddaspa already knew how to solve my issue in a very easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not really reproduce your problem without the data, but I suggest trying `.astype(str)` instead of `.astype('category')`.

Another way to get the correct data could be to use `np.unique(some_array, return_counts=True)`. [See here for more](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple fix! This solution should be perfectly fine for all I want to do with it. I'll close the issue :)

I tried to create a nice reproducible example, but the output is not really looking nice. I will work on this for my next question on stackoverflow. 

Thanks for the help!